# Wrap javascript text by a certain amount of words

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some string text that I get from an API. I am displaying it in an outlook-addin which is just html, javascript and css.

I am putting the string of text in a panel window which is small. I have been trying to wrap the text using css or javascript but so far no luck.

Here is the code:
Javascript:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let text = "Subject: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].subject) + "<br>"+
        "CC Emails: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].cc_emails).replace("[]","No Emails are CC'd").replace("[","").replace("]","") + "<br>" +
        "Ticket Creation Date: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].created_at) + "<br>" +
        "Ticket Status: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].status).replace("2", "Open").replace("3", "Pending").replace("4", "Resolved").replace("5", "Closed").replace("6", "Waiting On Customer") ;
        let pre = document.createElement('pre');
        
        
        pre.innerHTML = text;
        pre.style.cssText += 'font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;width:30px'
        
        output.appendChild(pre);
```

html:

```
<div class="ms-PanelExample">
    <script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <button style="margin:1px;" id="get-freshdesk" class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary">
      <span class="ms-Button-label">Freshdesk Tickets</span>
    </button>
  <div class="ms-Panel ms-Panel--xxl">
    <button class="ms-Panel-closeButton ms-PanelAction-close">
      <i class="ms-Panel-closeIcon ms-Icon ms-Icon--Cancel"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="ms-Panel-contentInner">
        <style>
            ms-Panel-headerText{
                width: 10px;
                height: 100px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                inline-size: min-content
                
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
      <p class="ms-Panel-headerText">Freshdesk Integration</p>
      <div class="ms-Panel-content">
        <span class="ms-font-mfresh">Latest Ticket information</span> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yet the text still keeps getting cut off:
[image]

I also tried changing the `ms-Panel-headerText` to `pre` in the css style section but no luck.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Taken from the MDN web docs: "The <pre> HTML element represents preformatted text which is to be presented exactly as written in the HTML file. ". Maybe try any other element, like a <p> or <div>

Comment: That did the trick! I used `p` instead and used 'font-size:16px;font-weight:bold; width: 350px; word-break: break-word;' for the css. If you make an answer I will give you the credit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment.

When you look at the documentation about the `pre` element on MDN Web Docs, it states:

> "The  HTML element represents preformatted text which is to be
> presented exactly as written in the HTML file. "

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

So try any other (inline-)block element and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Pre displays text just as it is in your code file so no word-wrap is applied.

However this seems to work if you really want it to be wrapped in pre tags.

```html
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; ">
    The purpose of lorem ipsum is to create a natural looking block of text (sentence, paragraph, page, etc.) that doesn't distract from the layout.
    </pre>
```